# dojo animation for buttons, images, and text

Tags: javascript, animation, dojo

Hi i was trying to make an animation in dojo. When a button was hovered over, the image would jump up and text would change to yellow color. i use dojo functions but got an syntax error

```
    require(["dojo/mouse", "dojo/on", "dojo/dom"], function(mouse, on, dom){
          on(dom.byId("button1"), mouse.enter, function(evt){
            checkLegendStatus();
            require(["dojo/_base/fx"], function(baseFx) {baseFx.animateProperty({node: "b1img", properties: {top: { start: 0, end: -10 }},duration: 200, onEnd: function()
            {
                dojo.style("caption1", "color", "#ffd152"); 
            }).play();

          });
        });
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

just found out i left one function open, it should be

```
                require(["dojo/mouse", "dojo/on", "dojo/dom"], function(mouse, on, dom){
          on(dom.byId("button1"), mouse.enter, function(evt){
            checkLegendStatus();
            require(["dojo/_base/fx"], function(baseFx) {baseFx.animateProperty({node: "b1img", properties: {top: { start: 0, end: -10 }},duration: 200, onEnd: function()
            {
                dojo.style("caption1", "color", "#ffd152"); 
            }}).play();

          });
        });
```